# How do I use Java fx pdf viewer?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Does anyone have a recommended way to view a PDF file by using javafx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [JPedalFX](http://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedalfx-viewer/) viewer which provides a JavaFX component for viewing PDF files.

OR

Pre-convert the PDF into JavaFX code prior to viewing using the [JPedal PDF to JavaFX converter](http://www.idrsolutions.com/convert-pdf-to-javafx/).

Comment: JPedal is not open source. Is there any open source api to do the same ?

Comment: I don't know of any open source API for PDF display in JavaFX, [StackOverflow isn't really a place for software recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource).  According to StackOverflow standards, I probably shouldn't even have answered this question in the way I did.  You could review some of the other answers to this question to see if any of the software recommended there helps you otherwise you can research or ask questions on a different site.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate issues: PDF and display.

Java FX is your display.

You can generate PDFs using XSL-FO if you have XML to start with and like writing stylesheets, OR you can do it with Java code if you use the iText library.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, this line just opens pdf files in the OS (so not embedded or anything, you'll need a program installed that can handle pdf's like Adobe Reader):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

The following thread from stackoverflow.com discusses different possibility to develop a pdf viewer for the javafx application.
[Displaying pdf in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207116/displaying-pdf-in-javafx)

The following libraries can be tried for this implementation:

```
OpenViewerFX – An Open Source JavaFX PDF Viewer: https://www.idrsolutions.com/openviewerfx/
PDF renderer with Java: https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer
PDF.js
JPedalFX
SwingLabs
```