# How open and watch pdf using Java swing or JavaFX

Tags: java, pdf, javafx

*How open and watch **pdf**  using Java swing or JavaFX*?

I want to create reader in my user GUI,can your help me

Comment: There is [JPedal](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/javafx-pdf-viewer), but unless your requirements are limited , you should better implement a solution with [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Comment: Already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207116/displaying-pdf-in-javafx

Comment: Probably already done before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207116/displaying-pdf-in-javafx