# JavaFx view pdf in Popup without using JxBrowser Plugin

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

> I am trying to develop a **javafx** webview browser. I have a website
>   developed in **PHP** that I need to display through the **javafx** web
>   browser. Popups browser window is generated using javascript window.load() function, and the content of pdf is is in base64 format.

*Following is the javascript code showing popup*

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + <BASE64_STRING>,"_blank","menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,width=600,height=700");
```

> I stuck displaying pdf files on browser popup. When I am
>   running the same website in chrome or safari it works fine showing
>   popup with pdf or doc files. Since javafx don't have pdf support by
>   deafult I may need some third party libraries or some other
>   techniques. I still badly consuming 2 days for finding the solution. Can
>   anyone help me in this case please? Thank you very much in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the [JPedalFX](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/java-pdf-viewer) library. For further information see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219416/4823977

Comment: I followed JPedalFX libarary, there we should provide the path of pdf file. but my case is display pdf from base64 encrypted data and it generated dynamically. I followed jxBrowser it has full featured functionalities. But its a bit costly. Thank you for reply @Mark

Comment: @BipinKareparambil Convert the base64 string to a blob and save it as a file temporarily in the temp folder? Or you might be able to use the blob as file object to open JPedalFX.

Comment: JPedalFX is a pay library?! No thanks.