# How can I display a PDF file in a WebView (JavaFX) panel using PDF.js?

Tags: javascript, java

I got this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040344/3789572) solution, which code is below, but it isn't working. When I press the button, nothing is shown.
You can change the file paths and try it for yourself.

Can you help me?

Controller code:

```
package sample.principal;

import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

import java.io.File;  
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class WebController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private WebView web;

@FXML
private Button btn;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    WebEngine engine = web.getEngine();
    String url = getClass().getResource("..\\resources\\web\\viewer.html").toExternalForm();

    // connect CSS styles to customize pdf.js appearance
    engine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("..\\resources\\web\\viewer.css").toExternalForm());

    engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.load(url);

    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                // to debug JS code by showing console.log() calls in IDE console
                JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("java", new JSLogListener());
                engine.executeScript("console.log = function(message){ java.log(message); };");

                // this pdf file will be opened on application startup
                if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    try {
                        // readFileToByteArray() comes from commons-io library
                        byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("C:\\Users\\Felipe\\Documents\\" +
                                "Programação\\Java\\" +
                                "IdeaProjects\\PDFviewerStackOverFlow\\src\\sample\\principal\\teste.pdf"));
                        String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
                        // call JS function from Java code
                        engine.executeScript("openFileFromBase64('" + base64 + "')");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    // this file will be opened on button click
    btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        try {
            byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("teste.pdf"));
            String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
            engine.executeScript("openFileFromBase64('" + base64 + "')");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
}
```

The Main code:

```
package sample.principal;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch();
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("PDF test app");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 576));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

and the other one:

```
package sample.principal;

public class JSLogListener {
public void log(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
}
```

I would be very grateful for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your question have to do with C++, C or HTML?

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: The tags for the question are JavaScript (PDF.js) and Java.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("HTML");
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(500);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

    VBox root = new VBox();     

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(browser);
    webEngine.loadContent("<b>asdf</b>");

    root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
  }
  }
```